# Django - Include year and month in log filename the clean way

Tags: python, django, apache, logging

On our web service, we keep several logs which we want to be named as this: `usage_YEAR_MONTH.log`

This is the way we set it up in `settings.py` :

```
today = datetime.date.today()
log_suffix = "%04d_%02d" % (today.year, today.month)
LOG_DIR = "/path/to/log"

LOGGING = {
    # ...
    "loggers": {
        "usage" : {
            "handlers": ["usage"],
            "level": "INFO",
        },
    },
    "handlers" : {
        "usage" : {
            "level": "INFO",
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "filename": "%s/usage_%s.log" % (LOG_DIR, log_suffix),
            "formatter": "simple",
        },
    },
    "formatters" : {
        "simple": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s %(message)s",
        },
    },
}
```

Unfortunately every 1st day of the month, logs keep writing to previous month's log ... Up to a random time or when I do `sudo service apache2 reload`.

I know that one possibility would be to add a cron that launches this command early on every 1st of the month ... but what would be the clean way to do this?
Also ... what is the reason for this filename not being set for every single request? (I guess it's for optimization matter)

Comment: settings are loaded when the application starts up, and not on every request. That is why you get the datetime you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, django evaluates settings once when starting, and not on every request.

To do what you are trying to do, check out the [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) linux command. It will be quite easy to configure what you need using that.

Comment: @samb: Django/Python supports the `TimedRotatingFileHandler`, however for flexibility I recommend @zsquare's solution of using `logrotate` or another external tool. In that way you can reuse it for other servers like Nginx or MySQL.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler

Comment: @zsquare: Thanks. The key answer for me is that "Django evaluates settings once when starting". I began suspecting it. Because in our case it's really important that we can find and read back any log sorted by year_month we've not switched to logrotate (which don't do that). Instead I had to : 1) always output logs to simply named log files (like usage.log) and 2) monthly move these files to a year_month name (like usage_2014_06.log). I've made a simple Python script for that and a cron instruction.